# Initializing Queue or Stack with default values?

Tags: c#, stack, queue

You can Initialize a list with pre-placed values:

`List<int> L1 = new List<int> {1, 2, 3};`

is there an equivalent of above for Queue? My idea was :

`Queue<int> Q1 = new Queue<int> {1, 2, 3};`

which doesn't work. Is there any workaround?

Is

```
Queue<int> Q1 = new Queue<int>();
Q1.Enqueue(1);
Q1.Enqueue(2);
Q1.Enqueue(3);
```

the only valid solution?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use the constructor [`Queue<T> Constructor (IEnumerable<T>`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/69zckb8z.aspx)

```
Queue<int> Q1 = new Queue<int>(new[] { 1, 2, 3 });
```

Or

```
List<int> list = new List<int>{1, 2, 3 };
Queue<int> Q1 = new Queue<int>(list);
```

Comment: This solution requires instantiation of intermediate collection. The solution described in question does not. Of course it is obviously. But want to underline if someone misses it :).

Answer (score 4):

See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/madst/archive/2006/10/10/what-is-a-collection_3f00_.aspx and particularly:

> The meaning of this new syntax is simply to create an instance of
>   MyNames using its no-arg constructor (constructor arguments can be
>   supplied if necessary) and call its Add method with each of the
>   strings.

and

> The resulting language design is a “pattern based” approach. We rely
>   on users using a particular name for their methods in a way that is
>   not checked by the compiler when they write it. If they go and change
>   the name of Add to AddPair in one assembly, the compiler won’t
>   complain about that, but instead about a collection initializer
>   sitting somewhere else suddenly missing an overload to call.

A queue doesnt support the Add method and hence therefore can't be initialized with the short expression style syntax. This is really a choice by design. Luckily, you can pass a collection to the Queue's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Queue<int> Q1 = new Queue<int>(new int[] { 1, 2, 3} );
```